# Honorific on a number

Tags: grammar, keigo, honorifics

I've been having a play with Duolingo and I came across this utterance:

> 果物を**お一つ**どうぞ。

So far I've come across some pretty unnatural stuff and it's left me rather skeptical.
I've never seen an honorific on a number before. Assuming this is natural how should it be used? Can I add お to any number plus counter, and when should I do so?

Comment: I hear it pretty regularly from cashiers confirming the number of items I want (like from the hot food case).

Comment: 「お一人様ですか」But I don't think お or が is used with more than 2 people.

Comment: Typo: I meant お or ご

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, おひとつ is perfectly natural.

As @Eddie Kal pointed out in the comment, お一人様 is also very common, as well as お二人様 and おふたつ. And I fully agree with @Eddie Kal that お is not used with more than 2 people/pieces. According to [this site](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1284703442) apparently it's not impossible to say お三つ, but it's not only unnatural, but also it's rather unlikely that the interlocutor understands what you meant to say. Other than these cases, I cannot really come up with a case where お is used with numbers.

For おひとつ and おふたつ, I don't think whether with or without お really matters (especially in the example you mentioned above, I don't really see a particular difference), but for お一人様 and お二人様, it sounds weird if you say just 一人様. If you are not sure, say 一名様、二名様、三名様 etc. These are Chinese numbers and by definition お is not used (if ever Chinese words are used in the honorific form, it would be with ご, although in this case for some reason you don't need ご).

Comment: There's also お一方 (おひとかた), お二方 (おふたかた), and お三方 (おさんかた).